Expo Auth Session with Doorkeeper custom oAuth provider & devise
Using expo-auth-session for authentication in a react native app, the browser will open for you to login and you may notice it doesn't close on login/sign up - you may then try to login again and because the session in the browser is already set, it works..
To fix this - disable turbo on the devise forms and make sure the oauth/authorize executes as HTML rather than TURBO STREAM and it should work - the expo web browser doesn't know what to do with a Turbo Stream - hopefully someone saves a day or two with this.

See above, disable turbo on devise forms when authenticating from expo app

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
